# Como faço para que cada Card no GridView em flutter, possa abrir um link específico?

Tags: dart, flutter

Preciso saber como faço para diferenciar um card do outro na GridView do flutter? Pois preciso abrir, assim que clicado, um link específico para cada card.

Tenho um código que abre um site específico, mas o faz quando clicado em qualquer card, preciso que abra um link específico para cada card.

Segue o código que precisa da correção:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class Settings extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      body: GridView.count(
        // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
        // horizontal, this would produce 2 rows.
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        // Generate 100 Widgets that display their index in the List
        children: List.generate(6, (index) {

          return  InkWell(
            onTap: () async {
              await launch('http://tigreadvocacia.com.br');
            },
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 1.3,
                        child: Image.asset('images/image$index.jpg',

                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Título $index',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Associe o `index` da Grid a algum array com os links. lembrando que esse array deve estar em uma setState(). Pois o index funcionara com um cursor no seu array. Dê uma olhadinha no pluguin Http do fluter e veja a documentação ou alguma outra que lhe permita abrir um link e ponha o Widget dentro do Column também.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa associar os itens do `GridView` com os itens de um array. Supondo que você possui a seguinte classe:

```
class Site {
  Site(this.name, this.url);

  String name;
  String url;
}
```

E a seguinte lista:

```
List<Site> sites = [
  Site("Google", "https://google.com"),
  Site("StackOverflow em Português", "https://pt.stackoverflow.com")
]
```

Vamos montar o Widget:

```
GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  children: List.generate(sites.length, (index) {
    Site site = sites[index];

    return Card(child: Text(site.url));
  })
);
```

Veja que ao montar a lista, associo o índice com o item da lista.